# filter out columns where all values equal 1

Tags: r, filter, dplyr, subset

I have a huge data frame. I would like to filter the columns which all their values are equal to 1.

here is an example of my data.

```
A = c(1,2,3,4,5,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,1,4,5,6,1,1,1,1,1,1,2,3,4,1,3,3,1,1,1,1,1,1)
M  <- matrix(A, ncol = 6, nrow  = 6, byrow = F)


      [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6]
[1,]    1    1    2    1    2    1
[2,]    2    1    3    1    3    1
[3,]    3    1    1    1    4    1
[4,]    4    1    4    1    1    1
[5,]    5    1    5    1    3    1
[6,]    6    1    6    1    3    1
```

desired output is as follows:

```
      [,1] [,2] [,3]
[1,]    1    2    2
[2,]    2    3    3
[3,]    3    1    4
[4,]    4    4    1
[5,]    5    5    3
[6,]    6    6    3
```

I would like to use filter function from dplyr or other R functions. 
Do you have any idea how can I do that? 
Thanks

Comment: are you wanting to work with a matrix or a dataframe?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure which you mean, I'll provide both.

**Matrix**

```
M[, apply(M, 2, function(a) !all(a == 1)) ]
#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    2
# [2,]    2    3    3
# [3,]    3    1    4
# [4,]    4    4    1
# [5,]    5    5    3
# [6,]    6    6    3
```

**Data Frame**

```
D <- as.data.frame(M)
D[,sapply(D, function(a) !all(a == 1))]
#   V1 V3 V5
# 1  1  2  2
# 2  2  3  3
# 3  3  1  4
# 4  4  4  1
# 5  5  5  3
# 6  6  6  3
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `colMeans(M == 1)` to get the percentage of each column which equals `1`, then select those columns for which that percentage is not `1` (i.e. 100%).

```
M[, colMeans(M == 1) != 1]

#      [,1] [,2] [,3]
# [1,]    1    2    2
# [2,]    2    3    3
# [3,]    3    1    4
# [4,]    4    4    1
# [5,]    5    5    3
# [6,]    6    6    3
```

If you have a data frame, a `dplyr` solution is to use `select_if`

```
library(dplyr)

df %>% 
  select_if(~ any(. != 1))

#   V1 V3 V5
# 1  1  2  2
# 2  2  3  3
# 3  3  1  4
# 4  4  4  1
# 5  5  5  3
# 6  6  6  3
```

Note that both `colMeans` and `any` have a `na.rm` argument you can use if your data has `NA` values.